# If events $A$ and $B$ are independent and events $A$ and $C$ are independent, are events $A$ and $B \cap C$ independent?

Tags: probability, independence

Let $A,B,C$ be events such that $A$ and $B$ are independent and $A$ and $C$ are independent i.e. $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ and $P(A\cap C)=P(A)\cdot P(C)$. My question is whether this implies that $A$ and $B \cap C$ are independent i.e. whether $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)\cdot P(B\cap C)$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Neither of your hypotheses say anything about $P()A\cap B\cap C)$.

Comment: Yet, I am unable to find any counter-example.

Comment: If I understand your question properly, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Pairwise_and_mutual_independence) gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false.

Consider $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $P$ the uniform distribution. Let $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1,3\}$ and $C = \{1,4\}$.

Then $P(A \cap B) = 1/4 = P(A)P(B)$ and $P(A \cap C) = 1/4 = P(A)P(C)$.

But $P(A \cap B \cap C) = 1/4 \neq P(A)P(B\cap C) = 1/8$.

Answer (score 0):

Flip two coins, a dime and a quarter.

Event $B$: the dime comes up heads.

Event $C$: the quarter comes up heads.

Event $A$: both coins come up the same way, both heads or both tails.

$A$ & $B$ are independent, $A$ & $C$ are independent, $B$ & $C$ are independent,
but $A$ & $B\cap C$ are not independent.
$$P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac12$$
$$A\cap B=A\cap C=B\cap C=A\cap B\cap C$$
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A\cap C)=P(B\cap C)=P(A\cap B\cap C)=\frac14$$